# Java: split a list of Dates in sublists that rappresent ranges of days from original lists

Tags: java

I have a list of Dates ( or DateMidnight from joda time) i rappresent here the dates like text dd/MM/yyyy for semplicity, for example:

[ 01/01/2010, 02/01/2010, 03/01/2010, 05/01/2010, 10/01/2010, 11/01/2010, 22/01/2010, 23/01/2010, 24/01/2010]

i want to obtain from this list another list that contains sublists that rappresent ranges of continuous days from the original list, like this:

[ [01/01/2010, 03/01/2010] , [05/01/2010, 05/01/2010], [10/01/2010, 11/01/2010], [22/01/2010, 24/01/2010] ]

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addAll` those lists into a `TreeSet`; that will both make the list items unique and sort them.

Then initialize a `subList` to an empty list and loop through that Set.

- If sublist is empty, accept any date from the key from the set.
- if sublist is not empty, and the date from the set = last date in sublist + 1 day, add the new date to the set
- if sublist is not empty and date is not contiguous, dump your sublist to another list and start with a new empty sublist.
- When you're out of the loop, if the sublist is not empty then that's your last list to add to the list of lists.

---

Refinements.

Strictly speaking, your supercollection doesn't need to contain the list of dates for each subrange. You could optimize and simply store an object containing the begin and end dates.

Another optimization: The sublists you're storing also don't need to contain all your individual dates. Again, the begin and end dates would be fine.

I'd suggest you build yourself a class called DateRange, containing two dates.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have even number of dates in your list

```
List dateList = //contains the dates
Collections.sort(dateList);

List result = new ... // to store the list of intervals
for(int i=0; i<dateList.size-1; i+=2) {
    List interval = new ...// to store one interval
    interval.add(dateList.get(i));
    interval.add(dateList.get(i+1));
    result.add(interval)
}
```